# What is the correct way to keep a background service alive in WPF? (especially using Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have some services that I want to run forever in my WPF app, doing things like polling for app updates.

I am using [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/) and at the moment I have added these services as fields in my Bootstrapper, which I know will survive, and initialise them in `OnStartUp()`:

```
    private IHubConnectionManager hubConnectionManager;
    private IAutoUpdater autoUpdater;

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();

        hubConnectionManager = Container.Resolve<IHubConnectionManager>();
        hubConnectionManager.Initialize();

        autoUpdater = Container.Resolve<IAutoUpdater>();
        autoUpdater.Initialize();
    }
```

Does this seem ok? Or have I missed the idiomatic way of achieving this. My Googling has failed me so far...

Comment: You probably want to post this to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnStartup is as good a place as any to initialize your services.

If your services are singletons owned by your container, there's no need for your bootstrapper to also own them, though.

Comment: Thanks @canton7, the point about the container owning the singleton is very sensible and one that I hadn't though about! That should make it neater than holding on to these for no obvious reason in the Bootstrapper.